# Why Unicodes get converting from excel file to r data frame

Tags: r

I have excel file with unicode characters (like Korean and Japan language), when i load it from excel file to r data frame it's converting to  some codes. For example

Excel Source Column

```
values=KR|512207456|투비씨엔씨(주)
```

After load the excel file to

```
DF = KR|512207456|<U+D22C><U+BE44><U+C528><U+C5D4><U+C528>(<U+C8FC>)
```

I did lot of google to find the solution, unfortunately not able to find any solution. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Excel text *is* Unicode. That's why you can insert Korean text in the first place. There's nothing to fix here. What you see is how your IDE/Console displays non US-ASCII text. If you change the font or settings you'll see the actual characters.

Comment: BTW there are many similar questions, that assume there's some kind of Unicode issue when the *real* issue is how the data is displayed. How are you displaying that data? In the console? In your IDE? Which iDE is that? Which *versions* do you use?

Comment: Check for example [this question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-does-not-display-korean-chinese/30889). In Linux you need to set the charset to UTF8

Comment: Hey Kanavos i am using RStudio (version.string R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12))

Comment: On what OS and what are the environment settings? Eg `LC_TYPE` or `LC_ALL`. The *locale* doesn't matter, it's the character set that matters.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Entr and not sure where to check LC_TYPE, i did checked in env variable but couldn't find. May be please help on how to check LC_TYPE. Also one thing observed when i take df$columnname it's giving Unicode characters (Korean letters) , but when i simply run full data frame or export to csv it's shows following values <U+D22C><U+BE44><U+C528><U+C5D4><U+C528>(<U+C8FC>. Am i missing anything ? coz my requirement is i need to feed the solution from excel file and apply data cleansing and populate back to .csv format as extract.

Comment: Windows is natively Unicode since Windows NT. The only problem here is *RStudio*. The text wasn't modified, it's just that *RStudio* has problems *displaying* Unicode. The text is still there. If you export the frame into a new Excel file, or save it as a UTF8 text file or CSV you'll see it's still OK

Comment: For now i did work around, excluded problem columns and proceed with my cleansing process.

Comment: You didn't post any problem columns. You posted an RStudio bug. Do you have any reason to assume that text can't be used as-is? Did you encounter any *actual* problems?